# Bootstrap: why are my column not taking the full width but the last goes on different line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-float

why are my column not taking the full width but the last goes on different line?

[image]

[image]

sorry guys just realised they had margins on them. Thought it worked like flexbox

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is your css? What are the values of the class `thumbnail-1/2`?

Comment: Can you show CSS of thumbnail classes?

Comment: sorry guys just realised they had margins on them. Thought it worked like flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the margin from thumbnail and make an inner div which has a padding.

So basically remove the thumbnail classes from the column divs and add the thumbnail divs as child ones. Then change the margin css to padding

The margin makes it go onto the next line

HTML would be something like

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="thubmail-1">
                   Content
        </div>
 </div>
```

And css

```
.thubmail-1{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}
```

Or something like that (on my phone)